# 2D-3D array multiplication with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D (numpy) arrays from which I want to generate a 3D array in the following way: each of the **n** rows of the first array will multiply (elementwise) the second array to produce a new matrix, leading to **n** new arrays (forming a 3D array). I think a simple example will help to understand:

```
A = [[a11 a12 a13]
     [a21 a22 a23]]

B = [[b11 b12 b13]
     [b21 b22 b23]
     [b31 b32 b33]]

# The product "A*B" would result in a matrix C such as

C = [[[a11*b11  a12*b12  a13*b13]
      [a11*b21  a12*b22  a13*b23]
      [a11*b31  a12*b32  a13*b33]]

     [[a21*b11  a22*b12  a23*b13]
      [a21*b21  a22*b22  a23*b23]
      [a21*b31  a22*b32  a23*b33]]]

# Which is equivalent to (in numpy notation)

 C[0] = A[0]*B
 C[1] = A[1]*B
```

The fact is that the sizes are arbitrary (so not only **2x3** and **3x3**, of course the second dimensions are always compatibles), I am looking for a solution without "for loops". I tried for example to repeat the array B then multiply

```
B = numpy.repeat(B[nu.newaxis,:,:],2,axis=0)
C = A*B

# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (2,3,5)
```

But the new dimensions are not compatibles.

Comment: [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum) may help

Comment: If `B.shape` was (4,3), then the required adjustment might be clearer.  You'd want to multiply a (2,1,3) with a (1,4,3) to produce (2,4,3) (where the 1's are adjusted by broadcasting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
C = A[:, None] * B
```